# Excel SUMIF variations

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a SUMIF function like this one
`=SUMIF(OUT!$G$22:$G$70;'2018'!$B4;OUT!$J$22:$J$70)`

But i would like instead of giving the name of the sheet OUT, i want the excel to read de name of the sheet from an other cell like i show on the img.

I tried `=SUMIF(CELL("contents";E2)!$G$22:$G$70;'2018'!$B4;CELL("contents";E2)!$J$22:$J$70)`

but still not working. Anyone knows how to do it?

Excel image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need INDIRECT:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&E2&"'!G22:G70");'2018'!$B4;INDIRECT("'"&E2&"'!J22:J70"))
```

Note that since the ranges are literal text strings, you don't need to make them absolute since they won't adjust if you copy/fill anyway.